# Unacceptably slow bitcoin sync

Tags: bitcoin-core

Bitcoin core is currently 15 hours behind as I'm writing this and the piph (progress increase per hour) is at a STUPIDLY low speed. There are 95 blocks left but it says its going up 0.04% per hour. I've read that inscreasing the cache helps. Anyone else got some ideas on a fix? Or is this just how it is supposed to be?

Edit: Bitcoin core is also apparently using 50% of my disk which is not true. An application was using 12mb/s of disk and it was only using about 20% of the disk total. Bitcoin core however is using 3mb/s and is using 50%

Answer (score 3):

The usual bottlenecks for syncing are in CPU speed, memory limitations, or disk IO limitations. There isn't really a "fix" short of getting better hardware. The software is already doing as much as it can to sync quickly.

The only available "fix" is to increase the dbcache. Doing so will mean that more RAM will be used. To increase the dbcache, add `dbcache=<n>` to your bitcoin.conf file where  is the amount of memory you want to dedicate to this cache (note that Bitcoin Core will use more memory than you specify as it does other things that need memory besides the dbcache), or add `-dbcache=<n>` to the startup command, or, if using the GUI, increase the dbcache in the settings.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't understand bitcoin core, maybe you should look at alternative wallets.  Bitcoin core will take up massive disk space and typically you need a few days for an initial sync if you don't have SSD.  Mb/s is speed, not space.  Not sure what you are looking at there but it isn't going to give you an indication of what is going on.